# Understanding integral division

Tags: java, casting, integer-division

I have the following piece of code:

```
public static final long KILOMETER_IN_METERS = 1000;

public static int getKilometers(int distanceInMeter) {
    return (int) Math.floor(distanceInMeter / KILOMETER_IN_METERS);
}
```

And for the line with the **return** statement Sonar says:

```
Integral division result cast to double or float
```

[Here is the full description of this bug.](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/findbugs:ICAST_IDIV_CAST_TO_DOUBLE?layout=false)

As far as I understand, it says there is **int/int** division whose result could be a **floating value**, but I could be wrong.
How can I handle this case correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `Math.floor` here. `Math.floor` is an operation on `double`, and it does nothing when you supply an int to it.

> Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity)
>   `double` value that is less than or equal to the   argument
>   and is equal to a mathematical integer. Special cases:
>
> - **If
>     the argument value is already equal to a   mathematical integer, then
>     the result is the same as the   argument.**
>
>   If the argument is
>     NaN or an infinity or   positive zero or negative zero, then the
>     result is the same as   the argument.

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29))

The integer division already has the same logical behavior of `Math.floor`, i.e. it truncates the remainder of the division operation. `int/int` always returns an `int`.

For example, `100/3` would return `33`, and `40/50` would return `0`.

Simply use this code :

```
public static int getKilometers(int distanceInMeter) {
    return distanceInMeter / KILOMETER_IN_METERS;
}
```

Comment: Hah, you expanded your answer while I was expanding your answer. :)

Comment: Thank you Eran, but I have constant of **long** type and in result of `return distanceInMeter / KILOMETER_IN_METERS;` I've got exception because int expected, but long found.

Comment: @josser Well, there's no reason for your constant to be a long, since its value is quite small. If it must be long, you'll need the casting to int.

Comment: Yep, you are right - it's enough just to be an integer. As for Math.floor  - seems it unnecessary to use it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Math.floor` takes double as an argument, and integer by integer division is already an integer. So all the casting sonar whines about is done there, and not on your explicit cast to `int`.

Here's doc for `floor`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Eran's answer, here's what you're doing:

`distanceInMeter / KILOMETER_IN_METERS` divides an integer by an integer. In Java, that result is a truncated integer. Then you're putting that into `Math.floor`, which takes a double. So Java is trying to help you out, by making your `int` into a `double`. Then you're casting the `double` returned by `Math.floor` back to an `int`.

If you've been following along, you may have noticed that you had your truncated int already. So your code needs to be simply:

```
public static int getKilometers(int distanceInMeter) {
    return distanceInMeter / KILOMETER_IN_METERS;
}
```

Comment: that code does not compile, KILOMETER_IN_METERS is a long. you would need to cast it to an int first.

Answer (score 2):

When you divide two integers, you will always get an integer, rounded down.
if you divide `distanceInMeter / KILOMETER_IN_METERS` and then assign it to a double, it is first divided as `int`eger, before assigned, so you get a rounded down value, cast to an `double`.

Sonar does not complain because of `Math.floor` - it complains because you casted an integer-division result (which itself is an rounded-down `int`eger) into a `double`. Most of the time, this is an error (Why deliberately auto-round and immediately cast to a double afterwards)?

```
int distanceInMeter = 505;

double result = distanceInMeter / KILOMETER_IN_METERS;
System.out.println(result); // 0.0

double result2 = distanceInMeter * 1.0 / KILOMETER_IN_METERS;
System.out.println(result2); // 0.505

double result3 = ((double) distanceInMeter) / KILOMETER_IN_METERS;
System.out.println(result3); // 0.505

1.0 * distanceInMeter / KILOMETER_IN_METERS
((double)distanceInMeter) / KILOMETER_IN_METERS
```